# How to format date in bash to YYYY-DD-MMTHH:MM:SS.sss

Tags: linux, bash, date, format

can someone give me a point how to format data in bash with miliseconds? Thanks for help.

BR.

Petr

Comment: Just type `man date`?

Comment: I try to look at man date, but there is not how to format date properly.

Comment: Your `date` man page has nothing about `FORMAT`???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple. It is `date '+%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N'`.

Comment: Note that the quotes are not even needed. And `date +%FT%T.%3N` is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There is an even shorter solution.

```
date +%FT%T.%3N
```